# How to use same API in other view controller in swift?

Tags: swift, api

I am working on a quiz app where in one view controller I am showing the questions and when I click on any of the questions it navigates to other view controller and shows question with options. Now, I want to use the same API which I have used in first view controller in second view controller. How can I do that?

In the first view controller I have used a struct like this:

```
struct Questions {
    var id:String = ""
    var user_id:String = ""
    var questionset_id:String = ""
    var name:String = ""
    var type:String = ""
    var timetosolve:String = ""
}
```

In the second view controller I have used the same struct in a variable like:

```
var data : [Questions] = []
```

But the problem is that I am not able to use the variables of the struct in the second view controller. I have tried to use the variable like:

```
questionLbl = data.name //here cannot find any variable named as 'name'
```

Here, questionLbl is the label where I want to use the variable.

Comment: You should set the label's text with `questionLbl.text = data[0].name`

Comment: @Andre3000 It's crashing(index out of range).

Comment: you need to set the value of data when presenting the second viewController. `secondVC.data = firstVC.question` something like that. Are you using storyboard?

Comment: @Andre3000 I don't want to pass data here. Yes, I am using storyboad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` in first view controller and pass the data variable to the second one.

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourSequeIdentifier" {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? SecondVCClassName {
            secondVC.data = self.data
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore you can access your `data` variable from second view controller. Please note that `data` variable is an array and you can't access values it like this `data.name`.

Comment: Still can't access the variable.

Comment: @Simran Can you post how are you trying to access variable?

Comment: @Simran did you replace "YourSequeIdentifier" with your actual identifier set in interface builder? Did you cast `segue.destination` as correct view controller?

Comment: questionLbl.text = data.name - (value of type '[Questions]' has no member 'name')

Comment: I am not using segues.

Comment: let quizvc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
           quizvc.data = self.data
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(quizvc, animated: true)

Comment: You can't access array like this `questionLbl.text = data.name`. `data` is an array so you need to specify element you are trying to access e.g. data[0].name or data.first

Answer (score 0):

Your struct Questions should be declared in a global scope i.e in a new file "xyz.swift" or outside of ViewController class.

Which I am assuming as you said.

> In the first view controller I have used a struct like this: